# Problem with resultsize - A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'resultsize'

Tags: powershell, office365, pst

I want to get office365 mailbox list which Last logon was more than 180 days? and export their .pst files to another location?
Wrote this script

But i am receiving error like - A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'resultsize'
cant find where is the problem...

```
Get-MailboxStatistics -resultsize unlimited |
  Where-Object {$_.LastLogonTime -lt (get-date).AddDays(-180)} |
    Format-Table displayName,lastlogontime,lastloggedonuseraccount,servername
```

Comment: Hi, and welcome! Please format your code snippets for better readability. Also avoid aliases and use full names instead. (`Format-Table` vs. `ft`) I edited the post slightly.

Answer (score 2):

`Get-MailboxStatistics` has no `-ResultSize` argument. You should retrieve the mailboxes with `Get-Mailbox` and pipe results to get the statistics:

```
Get-Mailbox -ResultSize Unlimited | Get-MailboxStatistics
```

Comment: Thanks, modified script and it began work.
Get-mailbox -ResultSize Unlimited| Get-MailboxStatistics | where {$_.LastLogonTime -lt (get-date).AddDays(-180)} | ft displayName,lastlogontime,lastloggedonuseraccount,servername | Out-file C:\script\lastlogonMC.csv